# How to flip the edge of two connected triangles?

Tags: algorithm, math, triangulation, flip, edges

let's say I have two triangles with one shared edge. How can I flip the triangle order so that the two single points make up the new common edge?

Thanks

Comment: A picture might help us understand what you mean here.  And showing us what you've tried would be good as well.

Comment: I believe triangulation is not a correct tag for this question.

Comment: That depends on your triangle representation. If your triangles are (v1, v2, v4) and (v2, v3, v4), then the new triangles are (v2, v3, v1) and (v3, v4, v1). It is achieved by shifting the indices (+1 for each). Btw, the triangulation tag is quite appropriate, because this is used by the flipping algorithm for delaunay triangulation.

Comment: how does this make physical sense?  not clear what you want.  @NicoSchertler - if that is what is being asked, post it as a answer already.

Answer (score 2):

I assume, you want to change the triangle topology like this:

[image: Triangle flipping]

We'll consider the quadrangle (1, 2, 3, 4). It does not matter, in which direction the vertices are aligned (clockwise or counter clockwise). But you have to define one alignment at the beginning. This alignment can be interpreted as a permutation. This permutation is the mapping that will flip the edge.

If you have triangles (1, 2, 3) and (3, 4, 1) the mapping will be like this:

```
1 -> 2
2 -> 3
3 -> 4
    flipped triangle 1: (2, 3, 4)

3 -> 4
4 -> 1
1 -> 2
    flipped triangle 2: (4, 1, 2)
```

See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation#Notation) for information about cyclic notation of permutations.